# postgresql, Insert java analog of now() in Hibernate request

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

It is required to insert current timesmap with timezone in Hibernate request. How I can do it?

Comment: `new java.util.Date()` gives you the current date and time in Java. And HQL accepts expressions: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of what kind of request you use.

1. HQL [supports](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-expressions) current_timestamp function.
2. In native query, you may use standard SQL current_timestamp function.
3. Of course, you may take date from java (like JB Nizet said), and pass it as a parameter to HQL/[SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e8476) query